# Create or generate a control based on database results

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I create a control in a windows form application? I want to generate a textbox or a radio button when I select something from a Combobox. I basically want to query my database, and based on the values of the fields, I want to generate a textbox or a radio button. For example, if my query returns a value of "Textbox", I want to generate a textbox on the form in a specified location. How does one accomplish this?  Please help.

Comment: So do you want to generate the control based on combobox selection or on result of database query?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create the control manually in code and then add it to the `Controls` collection. Deciding which control to create depending on some input data (whether it's database query or a value selected from a combobox) is not much different then in any other case. Simple `if` will do the job. For instance:

```
    private void AddControl(string control)
    {
        if (control == "Textbox")
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
        else if (control == "Radio")
        {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.Location = new Point(200, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(rb);
        }
    }
```

Of course, it's very naive version. But it's only a starting point. I leave to you adding more advanced logic (like dynamically adjusting location, setting up properties of the radio button or the textbox, relying on `Type` instead of on a simple `string`, etc.)

The assumption is that you retrieve a `string` value from the database. For example in form's constructor:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string requestedControl = QueryDatabase();

        AddControl(requestedControl);
    }
```

I leave to you implementing the method to query the database.

In the question you also mentioned adding a control after selecting it in the combobox. In this case the only difference is that you rely on an event triggered after combobox's selection changed:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string res = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        this.AddControl(res);
    }
```

Here you rely on SelectedValueChanged event. Of course, in this case your combobox has to be populated with expected values (here "Radio" and "Textbox"). Also, you have to attach the event handler to the specific event on the combobox. You can do that in designer or by adding in the constructor the following line:

```
    combobox1.SelectedValueChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
```

Hope that clarifies the issue and sets up some starting point for you to continue from.